# How to add seed data for rspec tests in the scenario where Product has_one status and state machine acts on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, state-machine

I have two models `Product` and `Status`

In the product model, I have

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image_url, :name, :status_id

  belongs_to :status


  state_machine :status_id, :initial => :dead do 

    event :activate do
      transition all => :active
    end 

    event :de_activate do
      transition all => :dead
    end 

    event :set_out_of_stock do
      transition all => :out_of_stock
    end 


    state :active, :value =>  Status.where(:code=>"ACTIVE").first.id
    state :dead, :value =>  Status.where(:code=>"DEAD").first.id
    state :out_of_stock, :value => Status.where(:code=>"OUT_OF_STOCK").first.id
  end 

end
```

while running rspec, it tries to load Product model first and gives error saying that `nil.id` is 4 etc....as status is not populated.

How to preload status data before loading the model?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is the optimum solution, but you could place the state machine initialization (i.e. `state_machine` method invocation) in a Class method of `Product` and call that method explicitly after you've populated `Status`. I've tested this and it seems to work fine.